# Comma usage: Sentence starting with "But", sentential adverb, and followed by "when"

Tags: punctuation, commas, when, adverbials

I have a sentence structured as follows in a scientific text.

> But, in particular, when doing A, the system cannot do B.

I think all commas are formally required. However, for "But" in particular, I am always urged to omit the trailing comma, since doing a reading pause feels really awkward. The same holds for "But in particular" and to some extent for "But in particular when".

Question: Is there any rule that would allow omitting one of the two commas in the first part of the given sentence in a scientific text?

**Edit:** Here is an alternative summary of text, incl. the sentence before the "But".

> The previous solution avoids to make any assumptions on effect X. But, in particular, when doing A for objects Y1 and Y2, this may cause effect B.

Based on the discussion, I now rewrote this as follows.

> The previous solution avoids to make any assumptions on effect X. This may cause effect B, in particular when doing A for objects Y1 and Y2.

I did not move the "in particular" to the end of the sentence, to better emphasize the whole when clause, rather than only the "objects Y1 and Y2".

Comment: Omit the but altogether.

Comment: @123 considering the title that seems to be integral to the question

Comment: I also consider using  "But, when A in particular, the system cannot B." @123: The "But" is required to connect a previous statement.

Comment: @Juve What is the previous sentence? But is used to contrast a previous statement.

Comment: I think the example is stylistically weak. I'd dump the unhelpful commas and resequence to *But in particular, the system cannot do B when doing A*. Arguably even that remaining comma should be discarded too.

Comment: Thx, @FumbleFingers. Your comment helped me to rephrase my text and I also got rid of the "But".

Comment: @Juve: That's probably a good move! You haven't told us what preceding text those first three words refer back to. But ***but*** implies some kind of *contrast, refutation* of whatever came before, whereas ***in particular*** would normally introduce some specific detail *supporting* an earlier statement, so it's not easy to come up with contexts where they work well together.

Comment: There are other problems in your sentence. 'Avoids to make' is not good grammar, and the 'in particular' is unneeded. I would rewrite as follows: "The previous solution avoids **making** any assumptions **about** effect X. But when doing A for objects Y1 and Y2, this may cause effect B." Also, depending on the exact words, the second sentence is probably best reversed to "But this may cause effect A when...".

Comment: Thx for the hint on "making" and "about", I am just finishing my final text for the library these weeks. Just in time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to the original question about any punctuation rules. However, given the comments to the question, the conclusion for the underlying problem may be the following.

*If you are unhappy with unhelpful commas, your sentences may be stylistically weak and probably need to be rephrased.*

Comment: Actually I think this is an answer to the question, and rather a good one at that.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a style issue. As such, you can do what you feel is best or be consistent with a reputable style guide

*The Chicago Manual of Style* discourages the use of commas following *and* or *but* even if these words start a sentence or act adverbially.

As for your last example, I think you need some break for clarity, but I would use an em-dash rather than a comma.